# Activate auto-normalize in EDIT MODE ( for weighting manually...)

Tags: rigging

I can't find a way ( a place in blender...) where I can activate "auto-Normalize" for the vertex weighting  when I'm not in Weight Paint mode
Anyone knows where it's located ( or if it's just POSSIBLE )

Comment: For starters, please don't include characters in ALL CAPS because it seems like you are YELLING ;)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it exclusive for weight paint feature? In edit mode, you can run normalize operator form mesh menu:

[image]